# Issue with Button in AlertDialog (Floating off screen)

Tags: java, android, android-alertdialog

Here's an image of what my issue looks like:
[image]

That box at the bottom is the top half of a button. Whenever I've got too many Stock Options in the dialog box, it first forces the button off screen, THEN it scrolls.
I want the button fixed at the bottom of the dialog and then have the scrolling happen.

Here's the code:

```
public void buyStock(View view){
    Context context = getApplicationContext();

    //create ScrollView to hold everything
    ScrollView scrollView = new ScrollView(context);

    //generate content for dialog       
    LinearLayout dialogContainer = new LinearLayout(context);
    dialogContainer.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 400, 1);
    dialogContainer.setLayoutParams(params);
    dialogContainer.setPadding(15, 15, 0, 15);
    dialogContainer.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);

    //each hotel stock options
    for (int i = 0; i < hotels.size(); i++) {
        Hotel testHotel = hotels.get(i);
        testHotel.setPrice(200);
        View stockPicker = getStockPicker(testHotel);
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams pickerParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 100, 1.0f);
        pickerParams.gravity = Gravity.LEFT;
        stockPicker.setLayoutParams(pickerParams);
        dialogContainer.addView(stockPicker);
        stockPicker.setBackgroundColor(0xffffff);
    }

    scrollView.addView(dialogContainer);

    LinearLayout dialogLayout = new LinearLayout(context);
    dialogLayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);

    Button buyButton = new Button(context);
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams buttonParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 100);
    buyButton.setLayoutParams(buttonParams);

    LinearLayout buttonLayout = new LinearLayout(context);
    buttonLayout.addView(buyButton);

    dialogLayout.addView(scrollView);
    dialogLayout.addView(buttonLayout);

    ContextThemeWrapper ctw = new ContextThemeWrapper(this, R.style.AppTheme);

    AlertDialog.Builder buyStockDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(ctw);
    buyStockDialog.setTitle("Buy Stock: ");
    buyStockDialog.setView(dialogLayout);

    buyStockDialog.show();

}
```

Comment: I've tried a number of things so far but to no avail. I've tried adjusting the weight of the button to 0.0f (Someone said that lower weight views have more priority on the screen.), I cant' "Align Parent Bottom" since it's a Linear Layout and not Relative. I'm still very confused as to why this is happening and any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Why don't you try to set a simple XML based layout for the dialog using setContentView method?

Comment: Because the content is dynamic. I don't know what will be in the dialog box until the program calls it.

Comment: Did you know that dynamic content is possible with ArrayAdapters with a ListView or a AdapterView inside an XML based layout?

Comment: I'm a hard-coder. I understand the flow and dynamics of my program much better when the layout and content is generated from the code. Using the XML layout files is fine for me on static views but coming from a PHP background, I'm much more comfortable with the java side of view creation. Since using an XML layout for this will NOT fix the problem, please don't push that as a solution. It isn't one. If you notice, I'm already using the setContentView method. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Make dialogLayout a RelativeLayout, and then declare buttonParams as a RelativeLayout.LayoutParams (layout params are declared according the parent viewgroup type, which for buyButton is now a RelativeLayout).  Your also going to need to declare a RelativeLayout.LayoutParams for scrollView.

**note:** This code is in c#/monodroid, not raw java/android, so some quick porting of some of the methods and constants may need to be required, but shouldn't be too time consuming.

If this doesn't work out exactly trying experimenting with other combinations of the RelativeLayout position rules and/or gravity. Let me know if it doesn't work out.

```
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams scrollParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, some_height);

RelativeLayout.LayoutParams buttonParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 100);
```

Then, add these statements to control where scrollView and buyButton are positioned

```
scrollParams.AddRule(LayoutRules.AlignParentLeft);
scrollParams.AddRule(LayoutRules.AlignParentTop);

buttonParams.AddRule(LayoutRules.Below, scrollView.Id);
```

The for the getting the button on the bottom of the screen, try one of two things

```
buttonParams.AddRule(LayoutRules.AlignParentBottom);
```

or

```
buyButton.Gravity = Gravity.BOTTOM
```

Comment: Programatticaly, Relative Layouts are messy. I'm using LinearLayout because I know what it will do regardless of screen size. I've tried changing dialogLayout to a RelativeLayout and "buttonParams.AddRule(LayoutRules.AlignParentBottom);" but the end result was a dialog box that filled the screen 100% of the time. Not what I wanted. I know this can be done with LinearLayout since I've found others who said they fixed it with LinearLayout but they never gave specifics as to how.

Comment: Can you please post the associated layout file if there is one for this associated view ?

Comment: It's all dynamic. There is not layout file. Everything is java because the content is dynamically created. That's another reason I'm not using relative layouts. It's simplest to just add another view and know that LinearLayout will place the content one right after another.

Answer (score 0):

Try explicitly setting a fixed height to the scrollView

```
scrollView.LayoutParameters.Height = HEIGHT;
```

I think it defaults to WRAP_CONTENT if not specified, and is why its scaling.

You may have to set it in a layout file if you cant from code

```
<ScrollView
  android:id="@+id/scroll_view_1
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="100"/>
```

and then change

```
ScrollView scrollView = new ScrollView(context);
```

to

```
ScrollView scrollView = findViewById(R.Id.scroll_view_1, this);
```

Comment: I don't want a fixed height. I want the scroll view to scale. It SHOULD scale. However, the ScrollView should NOT force the button off screen. That's the only issue here.

Comment: If the scrollview scaled to wrap the size of the list, then it will never scroll, b/c it will always be as big as the content, and then you'd have to scroll the screen alll the way to the bottom of the list to get to the button, thus rendering you scrollview useless, unless you had something else in mind?

Comment: It actually does scroll. Unfortunately, it scrolls AFTER forcing the button off screen and not before. The button is not in the ScrollView. Look carefully. Both the ScrollView and the Button are inside of a container called dialogLayout. (Used as the layout for the dialog). dialogLayout is a LinearLayout with a Vertical orientation. First the ScrollView is added, then the Button. The size of the dialog is always (Button Size + Title Size + Scroll View Size) (ScrollView size never exceeding screen size.)

Comment: All of that works fine. The part that isn't working, is that once the content for ScrollView exceeds (Dialog Size - Title Size - Button Size) the button gets forced offscreen. The ScrollView Size should never exceed a certain size but should scale until that point. Unfortunately, there isn't a setMaxHeight() method for ScrollView. Any other ideas?

Comment: Oh, right, I got you. Yeah I've ran into this exact problem, and it was a beeotch to fix. I had count how many list items were present, and if it was less than a certain amount, I'd add a certain amount until the height reached a pre-defined value. I'll post another solution, its going to be a description.

Answer (score 0):

Try wrapping the scrollView in another LinearLayout, and set this new layout's height to a fixed width that keeps the button low enough to your liking. You can actually replace the Scrollview with a ListView, but don't do this until after at least trying to get this fix working first. ListViews scroll, but you'd still face this problem without this fix.

---

To fix the new issue you mentioned below (with some quick and dirty code, you should use trial and error to fix it correctly), try the following

```
//each hotel stock options
for (int i = 0; i < hotels.size(); i++) 
{
   // ...
}

if( hotels.size() < numberOfItemsNeededForCorrectView )
{
   for( int i=0; i < numberOfItemsNeededForCorrectView - hotels.size(); i++ )
   {
        View blankView = new View(context);
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams viewParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(1, 100);

        blankView.setLayoutParams(viewParams);
        blankView.setViewState(ViewState.INVISIBLE);
        dialogContainer.addView(stockPicker);
   }
}
```

You can try replacing your scrollView with a list view still and see if that fixes things.  You can also try tweaking layout and gravity settings until you get it, or trying introducing other layouts or reorganizing your layouts (or using RelativeLayout, its really not that bad).

Comment: That's what the current code does. Layout is wrapped like so:

[Dialog Layout set to: DialogLayout]

[DialogLayout]

[DialogContent]

[ScrollView]

[ScrollViewContent]

[/ScrollView]

[Button]

[/DialogContent]

[/DialogLayout]

Comment: I understand that, but try adding another one as I described, trust me.

Comment: I created a new LinearLayout called scrollWrapper and set the LayoutParams as follows: 'scrollWrapper.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 300, 1.0f));'
The end result is the opposite of my current problem. If I have enough content in the scroll view, everything is fine.
If there isn't enough content, the content is forced slightly behind the Title for the Dialog and creates empty space below it.

Comment: Thats weird, but not surprising, android is full of these anomalies. As a quick and dirty fix check my edit above...

Answer (score 0):

So, now in 2022 I've also had this problem. I've just set fixed size for ScrollView in fragment layout xml-file. When you have this problem, you can set, for example, 150dp or 200dp and be happy! And for more convenience, you can create special layout for landscape screen orientation and set fixed layout_height size there. I'm really confused that there's no information about this problem besides this page on the Internet.

```
<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="200dp">
    <!--your view into scrollView here-->
</ScrollView>
```